# Postgres - Configuration Change to Vacuum Requires Restart?

Tags: postgresql

In the postgressql.conf file, I'd like to turn on autovacuum and change the threshold to 100. Because changing the max_workers thread explicitly states that it requires a restart, I am inferring that turning authvacuum on and changing its threshold does not. Can someone confirm?

```
autovacuum = on         # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1   # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
                # their durations, > 0 logs only
                # actions running at least this number
                # of milliseconds.
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                # **(change requires restart)**
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 100   # min number of row updates before
                # vacuum
```

However, in the following post I found evidence for the opposite inference; note that effective_cache_size explicitly states that a restart is not required while autovacuum does not mention a restart:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: autovacuum is turned on by default. There is nothing you need to change for that to happen (unless you have turned it off manually before). You only need to restart Postgres if a setting explicitly states "needs restart" for all others a `pg_ctl reload` should do.

Comment: both autovacuum and the threshold properties were commented out by default in my configuration file. does that negate your first sentence? i switched them for this post. but, it sounds like you answered my question in your second sentence. when should i expect postgres to perform the first vacuum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a value in `postgresql.conf` is commented out, that means the default is used.

`autovacuum` defaults to `on`.

Run:

```
SHOW autovacuum;
```

to see the current value.

For more detail about a parameter use `pg_settings`:

```
postgres=> \x
Expanded display is on.

postgres=> select * from pg_settings where name = 'autovacuum';
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------------------------
name       | autovacuum
setting    | on
unit       | 
category   | Autovacuum
short_desc | Starts the autovacuum subprocess.
extra_desc | 
context    | sighup
vartype    | bool
source     | default
min_val    | 
max_val    | 
enumvals   | 
boot_val   | on
reset_val  | on
sourcefile | 
sourceline |
```

See the `context` entry? That tells you, for certain, when it can be changed. In this case, it can be changed at sighup time, which is a postmaster reload. So a `kill -HUP` of the postmaster, a `pg_ctl reload`, or a `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` will update the setting, causing a new value in `postgresql.conf` to take effect.

The same is true of `autovacuum_vacuum_threshold`.

In general, if the docs don't mention that you need a restart you'll usually instead need a config reload to have changes in the config file take effect.